# Unable to create a user - 400 bad Request... Google service account

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to create a user by using the Google admin sdk. However, I keep on getting the following exception: **Invalid Given/Family Name: FamilyName**. This my my code so far:

```
private PostMethod performPostRequest(Connection con,
                                          String url,
                                          String userObject)
            throws Exception {

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            LOG.info(SCHEDULER_LOG_INVOKING + url + SCHEDULER_LOG_LINE_FEED);

            post = new PostMethod(url);

            String accessToken = mDaoService.getSetting(con, GoogleSettings.TOKEN);
            post.addRequestHeader(HTTP_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, HTTP_HEADER_BEARER + accessToken);

            if (userObject != null) {
                post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(userObject));
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception("Entity is null");
            }

            int errorCode = httpClient.executeMethod(post);
            if (errorCode == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (post == null) {
            throw new Exception("Post object is null");
        }
        return post;
    }
```

My user object is a JSON format.
For example:

```
{
    "primaryEmail": "saurabh@doamin.com",
    "name": {
        "givenName": "Mike",
        "familyName": "tyson"
    },
    "password": "hello"
}
```

I really don't understand what am I missing or doing incorrectly.

Comment: Seems to be quite a clear error message. Can you show your userObject String?

Comment: Hi the userObject string string is in the updated post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some time after the original question, but in case this helps anyone else - I had this issue too, but resolved it by adding the ContentType header (Content-Type: application/json)